# Load conditionally codeigniter hooks

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter we have hooks pre_system or post_controller_constructor and other hooks. Which execute on every requests. I want to override the hooks or as per request type loading the CI hooks.

For now I checking the controller name in hooks.php file and loading the CI hooks as per controller name. Is this correct approach?

Comment: what do you mean by request type ? like ( get , post )?

Comment: Request type means - get, post, put request and where from I am getting the request. Like mobile or web request

Comment: There is no native codeigniter solution, but you could extend the core to do so ? is this ok ?